# In this python code, in the string why are there the values if {1}, {0} and {2}?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in range(1,13):
        print('{1} times {0} is {2}'.format(i, j, i*j))
```

I understand the for loop aspect but I am confused about the purpose of inserting the values into {} and the order they were inserted.

Comment: Are you asking why the string is not `{0} times {1} is {2}`, or what the numbers in {} *mean*?

Answer (score 2):

most likely no reason -- or the result of a refactor, if you do them in-order you don't need to specify the numeric positions (since python2.7)

so this works fine:

```py
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in range(1,13):
        print('{} times {} is {}'.format(i, j, i*j))
```

or if you want to retain the same order as the original one:

```py
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in range(1,13):
        print('{} times {} is {}'.format(j, i, i*j))
```

Comment: thank you, so to confirm, for python 3 I don't need to specify the numeric position?

Comment: Correct, it will do them in order if not specified - however you can still specify order if you feel so inclined, or for reasons such as using the same value multiple times in a string.